# Why is the probability current density $J$ zero when $Ψ$ is purely real or imaginary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, probability

My intuition says that there is both a real and imaginary part to Ψ, so having a purely real/imaginary Ψ cannot work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$J=\frac{i\hbar}{2m} (\Psi \frac{\partial\Psi^*}{\partial x} -\Psi^* \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x})$

Assume $\Psi$ is real then $J=\frac{i\hbar}{2m} (\Psi \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x} -\Psi \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x})=0$

Assume $\Psi$ is imaginary such that $\Psi=i\beta(x)$ then $J=\frac{i\hbar}{2m} (\Psi \frac{\partial\Psi^*}{\partial x} -\Psi^* \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x})=$

$$J=\frac{i\hbar}{2m} (i\beta \frac{\partial(-i\beta)}{\partial x} +i\beta \frac{\partial(i\beta)}{\partial x})=\frac{i\hbar}{2m}(\beta \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x} -\beta \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x})=0$$